# Finding the maximum value of electric field for a given two-dimensional charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, singularities, coulombs-law

Suppose you have a surface of finite area with a fixed surface charge distribution. Does a maximum electric field magnitude $|\vec{E}|_{max}$ exist for each and every possible surface area? **If yes, how shall we find $|\vec{E}|_{max}$ or any other value greater than $|\vec{E}|_{max}$?**

The electric field due to an arbitrary surface charge is:

$$\vec{E}=k \iint_A \dfrac{\sigma}{r^2}(\hat{r})dA$$

I tried to find it the following way but to no avail:

Let maximum value of $\sigma$ be $S$

Now unfortunately, we do not have a maximum value for $\dfrac{1}{r^2}$ because the field point can be as close as we want to the arbitrary surface charge. (The field at a point on the surface is undefined.) This is where I can't proceed further.

But we know even though the integrand blows up at points near surface charge, there in no blowing up of the integral at points near surface charge and it approximately equals $2 \pi k\ \sigma (\hat{n})$. Therefore there must be a maximum value for $|\vec{E}|$.

> Another try of mine:
>
> \begin{align}
> \vec{E} &= k \iint_A \dfrac{\sigma}{r^2}(\hat{r})dA\\
> &= k \iint_A \dfrac{\sigma}{r^2}(\hat{r}) \cos{\alpha} \sec{\alpha}\ dA\\
> &= k \iint_A \sigma\ (\hat{r})\ \sec{\alpha}\ d\omega\\
> \end{align}
>
> where
>
> $\alpha$ is the angle between $\vec{r}$ and unit normal vector to $dA$
>
> $d\omega$ is element solid angle
>
> Here again, unfortunately the maximum value for $\sec{\alpha}$ is infinity. And I cannot proceed further.

Comment: In free space the range of all electric field is infinite, it does not vanish.

Comment: As we get further away from the surface charge, $r$ gets smaller and consequently $\vec{E}$ also gets smaller. Therefore at infinity the electric field due to a finite arbitrary surface charge is zero. This is what I meant.

Comment: Ok just as long as you realize it never is zero, just like gravity

Comment: At finite distances from the surface charge, it never is zero.

Comment: Can you please tell whether it may be possible to find an upper bound for $|\vec{E}|$ due to an arbitrary surface charge?

Comment: Are you talking about an infinite sheet of charge? If so, @probably_someone answer applies.

Comment: @BobD: I am talking here about arbitrary finite surface charge with bounded $σ$

Answer (score 0):

**If infinite surfaces and arbitrarily high $\sigma$ is allowed:**

For an infinite flat plane with uniform surface charge $\sigma$, the electric field at all points in space is

$$\mathbf{E}=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\hat{\mathbf{n}}$$

where $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is the normal vector to the surface. The magnitude of the electric field at all points in space is

$$E=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$$

If $\sigma$ is allowed to be arbitrarily high, then $E$ can also be arbitrarily high, so there can be **no** upper bound on the electric field from an arbitrary surface charge.

As an aside, this also makes it clear that $E$ **does not always vanish at infinity** in this case.

**If the surface is constrained to be finite and $-S\le\sigma\le S$ for some fixed $S$:**

Suppose we have a finite flat plate with uniform charge density $S$, and parallel to it, we have another finite flat plate with uniform charge density $-S$. They both have a finite area $A$ and are separated by a distance $L$.

The electric field midway between the plates' centers will look like the of two infinite flat plates, plus a finite-size correction that depends on the quantity $L/A$ (in other words, the assembly looks more like two infinite parallel plates when the plates get larger or closer together):

$$\mathbf{E}=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}-f\left(\frac{L}{A}\right)$$

By making the plates big enough (while still having a finite area) or the spacing small enough, we can make the finite-size corrections arbitrarily small.

Now, add a second pair of plates of the same size and with the same surface charge distribution as before (so now we have two plates on one side with surface charge density $S$ and two plates on the other side with surface charge density $-S$) at $L/4$ and $3L/4$. Now the field midway between is:

$$\mathbf{E}=\frac{2\sigma}{\epsilon_0}-f\left(\frac{L}{A}\right)-f\left(\frac{L}{2A}\right)$$

You can keep adding more and more pairs of plates, closer and closer to the center charge, and make the electric field midway between arbitrarily large (and you can also make all of the finite-size corrections arbitrarily small). Since you can always add another pair of plates, you will never reach a maximum electric field, even with a constrained charge density.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am talking here about arbitrary finite surface charge with bounded $\sigma$.

Comment: @N.G.Tyson 1) Then you should definitely make that clear in your question, as it doesn't say that anywhere at the moment. 2) By "finite" do you mean a surface with finite surface area? 3) This answer still holds for bounded $\sigma$ (unless by "bounded" you mean "fixed"). For any value of $E$, however large, there exists a value of $\sigma$ that will produce that $E$ at every point in space.

Comment: @N.G.Tyson So the question you really want to ask is as follows: "Suppose you have a surface of finite area with surface charge density allowed to vary within a finite range bounded from above. Does a maximum electric field magnitude exist, is there a surface that allows one to achieve the maximum possible electric field, and, if so, what is that surface and magnitude?"

Comment: 2) Yes, by finite I mean a surface with finite surface area. 3) Upper bound of $\sigma$: A number $S$ which is greater than the values of all $\sigma$. Same goes for electric field.

Comment: I would prefer my question as follows: Suppose you have a surface of finite area with surface charge density allowed to vary within a finite range bounded from above. Does a maximum electric field magnitude exist for each and every possible surface area? If yes, how shall we find it?

Comment: @N.G.Tyson Wait, so you're asking for the maximum electric field _for a given surface_ on which the surface charge is allowed to vary within a finite range? Not the maximum electric field _among all surfaces_ where the surface charge is allowed to vary within a finite range? Those are two **very** different questions, and it would really be appreciated if you would clarify which one you mean next time you ask a question like this, because they require essentially completely different answers.

Comment: @N.G.Tyson Even then, the question is still somewhat underspecified. Are we given a surface _and a fixed surface charge distribution_, or, for a given surface, are we allowed to vary the surface charge distribution to maximize the electric field magnitude at any point in space over all possible surface charge distributions? In other words, are you asking for the maximum electric field _for a given surface and for a given surface charge distribution_, or are you asking for the maximum electric field _for a given surface and among all allowed surface charge distributions_?

Comment: Want to find the maximum electric field for a given surface and a fixed surface charge distribution.

Comment: May I know why the parallel plate analogy is being used here?

Comment: @N.G.Tyson This was my answer before it was made clear that both the surface and the surface charge density are fixed, and you were only asking for the maximum of the electric field as it varied in space for a particular given configuration.

Comment: probably_someone: Have you come up with a solution?